# How to attach an id to all instances of a regex match in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm implementing a search highlight feature. I've been able to use regex to find all instances of a particular keyword in my table, and highlight it. What I'm trying to do now is be able to jump to the next/prev highlight word using Enter and Shift+Enter resp. Here's what I'm currently doing:

```
highlightSearchKeyword () {
      const reviews = document.querySelectorAll('span[data-v-071a96ec=""]')
      const formattedKeyword = this.searchKeyWord.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, '\\$&')
      let count = 0
      reviews.forEach(rev => {
        const substring = new RegExp(formattedKeyword, 'gi')
        let description = rev.innerText
        if (formattedKeyword !== '') {
          try {
            count += description.match(substring || []).length
          } catch (error) {
            count += 0
          }
        }
        description = description.replace(substring, match => `<span class="highlight" id="search-${some-id}">${match}</span>`)
        rev.innerHTML = description
      })
      this.highlightedWordCount = count
    }
```

As you can see, I'm replacing each match with a string that surrounds the original match word by a `<span>` tag. I want to give each instance of a match an id, so that I can do something like:

```
const elem = document.querySelector(`#search-{some-id}`)
elem.scrollIntoView()
```

If someone could help me out with this that'd be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `index` that `forEach` passes you:

```
highlightSearchKeyword () {
  const reviews = document.querySelectorAll('span[data-v-071a96ec=""]')
  const formattedKeyword = this.searchKeyWord.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, '\\$&')
  let count = 0
  reviews.forEach((rev, index) => { // *** Added `index` parameter
    const substring = new RegExp(formattedKeyword, 'gi')
    let description = rev.innerText
    if (formattedKeyword !== '') {
      try {
        count += description.match(substring || []).length
      } catch (error) {
        count += 0
      }
    }
    // *** −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−vvvvv
    description = description.replace(substring, match => `<span class="highlight" id="search-${index}">${match}</span>`)
    rev.innerHTML = description
  })
  this.highlightedWordCount = count
}
```

Or if you need to do this more than once and may end up with the same IDs that way, have a variable you increment as necessary;

```
// Somewhere in code that `highlightSearchKeyword` closes over:
let nextId = 1;

// Then:
highlightSearchKeyword () {
  const reviews = document.querySelectorAll('span[data-v-071a96ec=""]')
  const formattedKeyword = this.searchKeyWord.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, '\\$&')
  let count = 0
  reviews.forEach(rev => {
    const substring = new RegExp(formattedKeyword, 'gi')
    let description = rev.innerText
    if (formattedKeyword !== '') {
      try {
        count += description.match(substring || []).length
      } catch (error) {
        count += 0
      }
    }
    // *** −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−vvvvvvvv
    description = description.replace(substring, match => `<span class="highlight" id="search-${nextId++}">${match}</span>`)
    rev.innerHTML = description
  })
  this.highlightedWordCount = count
}
```

---

Side note -- Re: `new RegExp(formattedKeyword, 'gi')`, two things:

- If `formattedKeyword` has any characters in it that have special meaning to regular expressions (like `()` or `$` or `^` or...), the regular expression won't be what you expect it to be. [This question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript) have various implementations of an "escape" function for regular expressions you could use to avoid that concern.
- Note that it will do a substring match (it'll find `nan` in `banana`, for instance). If that's what you want, great, but if not add `\b` at the beginning and end.

Comment: Thank you! Your second suggestion worked perfectly. I'll keep in mind the formattedKeyword advice. For now it is working as I need it to, but if I ever need to change the behaviour of the search in the future, this will definitely come in handy! :D